# Doctrine2 throwing 'No Entity in Identity Map'

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm pulling a base entity out of the database, cloning it inside a loop to create new entities, changing some details and then persisting the entity.

For some reason this is throwing `No Entity in Identity Map` in `addToIdentityMap` in `UnitOfWork` when calling `EntityManager->flush()`.

I've also tried creating an entity and manually setting all properties in one to the other, no difference.

I'm not particularly familiar with doctrine internals, whats going wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the code of your entity?

Comment: Its just setters and getters, literally nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `__clone` method to the entity class to null out the identifier so Doctrine recognizes it as a new entity:

```
public function __clone()
{
    if ($this->id) {
        $this->id = null;
    }
}
```

Note the method is modeled [after Doctrine's docs for safely implementing `__clone`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/implementing-wakeup-or-clone.html#safely-implementing-clone)